# Is short-hand (type different) true/false comparison good practice on strings?

Tags: javascript, performance, types, casting, type-conversion

Is short-hand (type different) true/false comparison good coding practice on strings?

Example:

```
var is_this_true = "Something in here, so not empty.";
if (is_this_true) {}
```

Also, if any, what is the performance compared to strict comparison.
Example:

```
var is_this_true = true;
if (is_this_true === true) {}
```

Does the first example have to go through loose comparison (IE, same as == )

Comment: Well with strict comparison, that would never work. The types aren't the same. If you want to be more explicit, you might want to check the `.length` property

Comment: Nothing wrong with it in JS, but you can be explicit if you prefer. Given your string example: `is_this_true.length > 0` For your second example, don't worry about performance until you have a performance problem.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: That will throw if it's `null`.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I was just addressing the immediate question of short hand (type different) evaluation. In other words, given that it's a string, passing it to be evaluated as a boolean. So given a string, one can be explicit by comparing its `.length`.

Comment: Yes. That was my main concern. I knew there would have to be a type cast there, so although I know it's an accepted practice - does that make it a GOOD coding practice?

Comment: It's considered good practice insofar as one considers loose typing to be a good language feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `if (x)` checks whether `x` is *truthy* – any value except `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, `NaN`, or `undefined`.

This is done the same way whether `x` is a boolean or some other value, and is not related to coercing ("loose") equality.

Answer (score -1):

Empty string is always false and also following values if you use == comparison : false, '', "", 0, null, undefined

Comment: sorry)just for full list)

Comment: If you use `==` comparison, those values are not all equally considered `false`. If they were, then `null == 0` would be `true`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: You're right; he's confusing falsiness with loose equality.